# Rendering multiple scenes and joining them into one

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, workflow, transparency, scene

I am starting a new architectural project of an airport, and I am trying to create a scene where an aeroplane is landing on the runway. Now before I even start doing it, I am interested to know if it is possible to split a scene into more scenes, then render them separately and eventually join them back together.

What I want to do is to render whole stationary scenery (terminal building, runway, landscape etc.) without sky and airplanes in only one scene just as one frame (which will then represent a backgound of an animation), then just render airplane landing in one animation with everything else in the background transparent, and at last render the animated sky with dynamic clouds without everything else.

All of these three scenes will be rendered from one camera perspective.

My question is, can I once they are all finished rendering join them back together to make one animation? Is there something I should do in compositor, in video editor or do I have to use completely different program to do this?

Thank you very much in advance. If you have any other questions please ask.

Comment: This can be easily done, you don't even need separate scenes, all you need to do is set up separate [Render layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html).If you want you can also render from separate scenes, and then join everything in the compositor.

Comment: Tip: if you try to bring in different files, export your render in the openEXR multi-layer file format. This way, your render passes will be saved when opening this file in the compositor!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you for your quick response. I was thinking about doing the first method with render layers, but since I am modeling in a completely different program, and using Blender only as a rendering engine, the scene would still be imported into Blender as one layer only, so I would have to do the layer separation work all over again. So I assume I will have to stick to the compositor method (even though I have no idea of how to do it, but I'll give it a go). Thanks again for your help, have a nice day.

Comment: @BertVdB Hello, thank you for the tip, I'll have that in mind too if necessary. Have a nice day.

Comment: Just to be clear, both methods will use the compositor as final step to join everything together. The scene separation method before that is the only thing that differs, choose whichever best suits your particular needs. Layers or different scenes will mostly work the same. As Bert mentions be sure to render in openEXR format for best quality

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Okay, thank you very much again, I'll try to do it and I will see where am I gonna come at the end. Cheers!